# Using one angularjs controller in two pages with options?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one controller in AngularJS and one working page. Now I would like to use this controller on another page as well, but I need some options depending on where I called it. Especially before any code is running.

My controller:

```
angular.module('tutorialApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function(){
   var vm = this;
   vm.myOption = false;

   init();

   function init() {
       if (vm.myOption)
         doSomethingSpecial(); 
   }
});
```

In my html I would like to use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm" ng-init="vm.myOption= true">
```

But this calls ng-init after `init()` method. Is there a workaround?

Comment: since you have different pages so route/state must be different which can be used to check or You can use route params,

Comment: Or create a component or directive that passes bindings into controller

Comment: The reason `ng-init` gets called before your controller, is because ng-init runs when DOMready, while `init()` would run during angular bootstrap process.

Comment: What about `ng-init="vm.myOption= true; vm.init()"`?

Comment: I agree with @Satpal. I already did that multiple times: it's on my router config where I define the combination controller/template, and you can add some parameters there.

Comment: I would stick with using route params, using route resolve or create a angular component that receive the options as an input binding.

Comment: @Tatarin that is not true and is backwards from sequence explained in question which is as expected. Controller runs before view is compiled

Comment: @charlietfl http://jsfiddle.net/7ztap7f2/1/ ng-init would always be on DOMready and last thing that runs at a digest. Please ellaborate on your reply

Comment: Thank you. Using route wasn't on my mind. And when I refactor a bit, even vm.init() would be useful. I hadn't thought on this... Thanks all!

Comment: @Tatarin no, not on dom ready....it runs when angular compiles the dom **after** the controller is run to create the scope